# JavaScript convert leading zero number to string or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Normally we can easily convert a number string using `toString()` method or concat `''` with it.
But when number with leading zero like `01010` I can't convert it to plain string like `(01010).toString()`

Also how can I convert it to string?
Number is `01010` expected output `'01010'`

How to convert leading zero number to array in JavaScript?
Number is `01010` expected output `[0,1,0,1,0]`

Comment: Numbers starting with zero would be interpreted as octal. `01010` (octal) = `520` (decimal). JS does not keep the literal representation you gave it initially, just the decimal value. If you need to work with `"01010"`, you need to pass it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#syntax) (i.e. the base system of the given number) in [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#examples) method. By default any number starting with a `0` is assumed octal (base 8). So go like this:

```
(01010).toString(8)
```

Comment: There should be a way to find the radix of an unknown number as well in js, so you could go `var x = (010101) /*any number*/; var y = FindRadixFunc(x); x.toString(y);`

Comment: No, there is no way to find the radix of a number. All numbers are held in *exactly* the same representation. You can express them via different literals (e.g., `052`, `0o52`, `0x2a`, `0b101010` are all the *same* value representing decimal `42`) but that is not information that is retained once you have a numeric value. Similar to how you can do `x = 42; y = 40 + 2;` and there is no way of knowing which one was not a literal but came from a mathematical expression.

Comment: @VLAZ Even mathamatically we cant find the radix, 10 can be 2 in binary and ten in decimal. I realised my comment is technically incorrect.

Comment: The output of ```(01010).toString(8)```  is ```"1010"``` my expected output should be exact same thing but string like ```'01010'```
For ```0001010``` expected output ```'0001010'```

Comment: @webHasan there won't be more than one leading zeros ever. You can't have a number like `00000123` come across in js, it will always come as `0123`.

Comment: Actually there is no real world use of it but  sometime it require to do problem solving stuffs.

Comment: @webHasan Even for problem solving stuff, I don't think we can have `0000001010` in javascript. It's just it won't exist programmatically. Even in user agent environment all leading zeros will be converted to single leading zero, e.g. `var x = 00000019;` will be saved as `019`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the leading `0` the number is parsed as an `octal` (base 8).

- You can convert to base 8 using [`array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and add back the leading 0.
- From there you can use [`array#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert into an array.

**Convert to base 8 and re-add leading `0`:**

```js
"0" + 01010.toString(8) //> "01010"
```

**Split string into array items:**

```js
("0" + 01010.toString(8)).split("") //> ["0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]
```

**Demo:**

```js
function octalToArray(octal) {
  return ("0" + octal.toString(8)).split("")
}

console.log(octalToArray(01110))
console.log(octalToArray(01110010))
```

Comment: Actually I am searching a dynamic way. So that I don't need to add zero before it. 
I can make it string whether there is one leading zero or more like  ```01010```   ```001010```  ```0001010```